# codenameone and Opentok native interface

Tags: android, ios, codenameone, opentok

I am trying to implement step 5 of : https://tokbox.com/developer/tutorials/android/basic-video-chat/#connect

I am stuck at point 4 and 5.

I don't know how to implement them (I am a new user of codename one).

I don't know if I have to use a lifecyclelistener (and if so how?, because I do not find documentation) and if not what should I do?

Thank you for your help,
Amina

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sample just uses the activity since it works top to bottom but I doubt you need that. My guess is that you can probably create your own class and instance and instead of using:

```
mSession.setSessionListener(this);
```

You can probably just use:

```
mSession.setSessionListener(myObject);
```

Where myObject would just be a class you create and place next to the regular native class that implements this interface.

Another point of interest is the `onCreate` or other callbacks you might need. `onCreate` can probably be mapped to our lifecycle methods thru a native interface but you can also use `addLifecycleListener` which should work roughly like this:

```
com.codename1.impl.android.AndroidNativeUtil.addLifecycleListener(new LifecycleListener() {
  public void onCreate(android.os.Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     // ... on create code
  }
  public void onResume() {}
  public void onPause() {}
  public void onDestroy() {}
  public void onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle b) {}
  public void onLowMemory() {}
});
```